# java mysql specify column always error

Tags: java, mysql

i need to specify column name when update sql. (use ?=?)
always get error info like below:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL 
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near ''d11'=1 where cityid=11143'
at line 1
```

code snippets

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    pstmt  = conn.prepareStatement("update usercityday set ?=? where cityid=?");
    for (int i = 1; i < 91727; i++ ) {
        for (int j = 1; j < 32; j++ ){
            if (map[i][j] != 0){
                pstmt.clearParameters();

                pstmt.setString(1, "d" + String.valueOf(j));
                pstmt.setInt(2, map[i][j]);
                pstmt.setInt(3, i);
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
                ic++;
                if (ic %1000 == 0) {
                    conn.commit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't set the column Name afterword because the SQL is precompiled when using PreparedStatements. You could either use Statements (may cause SQL injections | bad) or you set the column name before creating the Statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your first ? in ?=? is not a String value. It is part of the SQL code. You are generating such code:

```
update usercityday set 'd11'=11143 where cityid=2
```

This is not a valid SQL.

A simple solution would be to specify the Statement inside the loop and do a String concat of the SQL Query like this:

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
for (int i = 1; i < 91727; i++ ) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 32; j++ ){
        if (map[i][j] != 0){
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("update usercityday set d"+String.valueOf(j)+"=? where cityid=?");
            pstmt.setInt(1, map[i][j]);
            pstmt.setInt(2, i);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            ic++;
            if (ic %1000 == 0) {
                conn.commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```